# iText7 PdfHtml and Jsoup incompatibility

Tags: java, jsoup, itext7, pdfhtml

Itext7 pdfHtml use own fork of Jsoup library. 
While i try use Jsoup 1.11.2 , application throws 
`Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task. java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/jsoup/Connection;` because use patched class Jsoup from pdfHtml.

How use different version for different point ?

Comment: This should be resolved in pdfHTML 2.0 (depends on iText 7.1), which will be released REAL SOON.

Comment: This will be realeased soon.